# Table width/height from CSS

Tags: css, height, width

How to get Width/height of the below CSS Class (dv, dvColumn) (below code I got it from View source)

```
<table id="LossDetailsPanelSet:12" class="dv "><tr><td valign="top">
<table id="LossDetailsPanelSet:13" class="dvColumn" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
var width = document.getElementByClassName('dv').style.offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementByClassName('dv').style.offsetheight;
var widthColumn = document.getElementByClassName('dvColumn').style.offsetWidth;
var heightColumn = document.getElementByClassName('dvColumn').style.offsetheight;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm getting "Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementByClassName' " , I',m using IE11

Comment: then you can try using getElementById('idname') instead of getElementByClassName

Comment: I tried both getElementByClassName as well as getElementById(LossDetailsPanelSet:12) too, but both of not working

Comment: please post more of your code.. as this is the possible solution for the two line code that you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var width = document.getElementsByClassName('dv').style.offsetWidth;    
var height = document.getElementsByClassName('dv').style.offsetHeight;
var widthColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('dvColumn').style.offsetWidth;
var heightColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('dvColumn').style.offsetHeight;
```